# Getting error 65096 while creating new user in oracle 18. How to create user in oracle 18 using sql-developer?

Tags: oracle

Getting error 65096 while creating new user in oracle 18. [image]

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete `CREATE USER` statement you used. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

You will get ORA-65096 if you are logged into the CDB (container database) and you try to create a non-common schema.

Normally application schemas are created in a PDB (pluggable database). I think this is what you probably intended to do.

Alternatively, if you intended to create an admin for all the PDBs, prefix the username with `C##`, e.g. `create user c##admin ...`.

Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMQS/GUID-DA54EBE5-43EF-4B09-B8CC-FAABA335FBB8.htm